# Помогите с компактным выводом в файл(ы) "выхлопа" от masscan?

Tags: bash, grep, awk

Имеется обычный выходной файл masscan'a(oL), мне необходимо вывести в отдельный файл каждый хост с его(уникальным)портом.

*(bash скрипт приветствуется)*

***Output:***

> ```
> open tcp 25 1.1.1.1 1153568607
> open tcp 587 1.1.1.1 1153568607
> open tcp 110 1.1.1.1 1153568607
> open tcp 22 1.1.1.1 1153568607
> open tcp 6687 1.1.1.1 1153568607
> ```

***Необходимо:***

**port25.txt**

**port110.txt**

..и тд.

***Либо то же самое, но с выводом такого типа:***

> **1.1.1.1:22**
>
> **1.1.1.1:110**
>
> **1.1.1.1:587**

Comment: непонятно, так что вы хотите чтобы попадало в файл, например port25.txt ? строки типа 1.1.1.1:25 ?

Comment: Да. Именно так и нужно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk '{system("echo "$4":"$3" >> port"$3".txt")}' FILE.IN
```